# Problem with painting non client area - Win32

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, win32gui

I'm trying to create custom non client area.

So I handled `WM_NCPAINT` message in WndProc method, and try to create a Red colored Rectangle in the non client area, but I found two problems with that.

1. The Rectangle I drawed in non client area also covers Client Area.

So to encounter it I added `RedrawWindow` function at the end of `WM_NCPAINT` message but I'm not sure its a good idea. What else I can do to correct this?

2. I got some weird result on resizing window many time. I just don't know how to explain it, but I try

This is what I'm achieved so far
[image: Final Result]

but if I resize it many times continuously (like 10 - 15) it gets this
[image: this is the problem]

the whole picture is the screenshot of the window (the first one).
I don't know what is happing with it. White part is draw wrongly and right and bottom part seems like transparent, but its all the screenshot of one window. (SS by snipping tool)

All mouse clicks pass through the transparent part.

Window is resize well but nothing drawn within it correctly, not with correct size.
The size of drawing is set to some maximum size (don't know what, it random).

The code is all same as the default code comes with the `Windows Desktop Application C++` Template of visual studio.

Just added the custom code for `WM_NCPAINT` message.

```
case WM_NCPAINT:
{
    HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hWnd);
    if (hdc) {
        RECT frame = { 0 };
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &frame);
        frame.right = frame.right - frame.left;
        frame.bottom = frame.bottom - frame.top;
        frame.left = 0;
        frame.top = 0;
        FillRect(hdc, &frame, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0)));
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        RedrawWindow(hWnd, &frame, (HRGN)wParam, RDW_UPDATENOW);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Clip out your client rectangle using `ExcludeClipRect`.

Comment: From [`CreateSolidBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createsolidbrush): *"When you no longer need the `HBRUSH` object, call the [`DeleteObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deleteobject) function to delete it."* You aren't doing that, and leak an `HBRUSH` per `WM_NCPAINT` callback. GDI resources are among the most limited resources your system has to offer.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks for suggestion but it gives me more trouble besides that I don't see any down fall of using ```Redraw Window``` function till now so I leave it as it is. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IInspectable's comment helps me.

From `CreateSolidBrush`: "*When you no longer need the `HBRUSH` object, call the DeleteObject function to delete it.*" You aren't doing that, and leak an `HBRUSH` per `WM_NCPAINT` callback. GDI resources are among the most limited resources your system has to offer.